# Unable to load Google Maps Properly in my Xamarin Cross-Platform App

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xaml, xamarin

I have a problem. I'm trying to show Google Maps on a Xamarin Cross-Platform App.

For Android, I have my API Key correctly generated an this code:

MainActivity.cs:

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace PruebaMapas.Droid
{ 
[Activity(Label = "PruebaMapas", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
}
```

Then, I have these on my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.PruebaMapas" android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<application android:label="PruebaMapas.Android">
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyD2bMPYdPUw_0Fd8-GkHle0_CiImTgtqX0" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

And I have this permissions enabled:

[image]

Then, I create a Page, called "MapPage.xaml" and here is the code:

MapPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="PruebaMapas.MapPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

MapPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace PruebaMapas
{
public partial class MapPage : ContentPage
{

    Map map;
    public MapPage()
    {
        map = new Map
        {
            IsShowingUser = true,
            HeightRequest = 100,
            WidthRequest = 960,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };
        // You can use MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius   
        map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(37, -122), Distance.FromMiles(0.3)));
        // or create a new MapSpan object directly  
        //map.MoveToRegion(new MapSpan(new Position(0, 0), 360, 360));  
        // add the slider  
        var slider = new Slider(1, 18, 1);
        slider.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => {
            var zoomLevel = e.NewValue; // between 1 and 18  
            var latlongdegrees = 360 / (Math.Pow(2, zoomLevel));
            Debug.WriteLine(zoomLevel + " -> " + latlongdegrees);
            if (map.VisibleRegion != null) map.MoveToRegion(new MapSpan(map.VisibleRegion.Center, latlongdegrees, latlongdegrees));
        };
        // create map style buttons  
        var street = new Button
        {
            Text = "Street"
        };
        var hybrid = new Button
        {
            Text = "Hybrid"
        };
        var satellite = new Button
        {
            Text = "Satellite"
        };
        street.Clicked += HandleClicked;
        hybrid.Clicked += HandleClicked;
        satellite.Clicked += HandleClicked;
        var segments = new StackLayout
        {
            Spacing = 30,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            Children = {
                        street,
                        hybrid,
                        satellite
                    }
        };
        // put the page together  
        var stack = new StackLayout
        {
            Spacing = 0
        };
        stack.Children.Add(map);
        stack.Children.Add(slider);
        stack.Children.Add(segments);
        Content = stack;
        // for debugging output only  
        map.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) => {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.PropertyName + " just changed!");
            if (e.PropertyName == "VisibleRegion" && map.VisibleRegion != null) CalculateBoundingCoordinates(map.VisibleRegion);
        };
    }
    void HandleClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var b = sender as Button;
        switch (b.Text)
        {
            case "Street":
                map.MapType = MapType.Street;
                break;
            case "Hybrid":
                map.MapType = MapType.Hybrid;
                break;
            case "Satellite":
                map.MapType = MapType.Satellite;
                break;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>  
    /// In response to this forum question http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22493/maps-visibleregion-bounds  
    /// Useful if you need to send the bounds to a web service or otherwise calculate what  
    /// pins might need to be drawn inside the currently visible viewport.  
    /// </summary>  
    static void CalculateBoundingCoordinates(MapSpan region)
    {
        // WARNING: I haven't tested the correctness of this exhaustively!  
        var center = region.Center;
        var halfheightDegrees = region.LatitudeDegrees / 2;
        var halfwidthDegrees = region.LongitudeDegrees / 2;
        var left = center.Longitude - halfwidthDegrees;
        var right = center.Longitude + halfwidthDegrees;
        var top = center.Latitude + halfheightDegrees;
        var bottom = center.Latitude - halfheightDegrees;
        // Adjust for Internation Date Line (+/- 180 degrees longitude)  
        if (left < -180) left = 180 + (180 + left);
        if (right > 180) right = (right - 180) - 180;
        // I don't wrap around north or south; I don't think the map control allows this anyway  
        Debug.WriteLine("Bounding box:");
        Debug.WriteLine(" " + top);
        Debug.WriteLine(" " + left + " " + right);
        Debug.WriteLine(" " + bottom);
    }
}
}
```

Finally, the screenshot I have when I run the app:

[image]

The output window says the next:

```
[0:] Width just changed!
[0:] Height just changed!

01-05 08:50:33.704 D/Mono    ( 8860): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps[0x9ebcb740] -> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement[0x9ebcb500]: 3
01-05 08:50:33.722 D/Mono    ( 8860): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android[0x9ebcb140] -> System.Core[0x9ebcc160]: 7
01-05 08:50:33.730 D/Mono    ( 8860): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
01-05 08:50:33.730 D/Mono    ( 8860): Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_float_method_a'.
01-05 08:50:33.730 D/Mono    ( 8860): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_float_method_a'.
01-05 08:50:33.730 D/Mono    ( 8860): Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_float_method_a'.
01-05 08:50:33.736 D/Mono    ( 8860): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0x9ebcb800] -> System.Xml[0x8af1bfc0]: 3
01-05 08:50:33.741 E/Google Maps Android API( 8860): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
01-05 08:50:33.741 E/Google Maps Android API( 8860): In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
01-05 08:50:33.741 E/Google Maps Android API( 8860): Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
01-05 08:50:33.741 E/Google Maps Android API( 8860): Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
01-05 08:50:33.741 E/Google Maps Android API( 8860):    API Key: AIzaSyD2bMPYdPUw_0Fd8-GkHle0_CiImTgtqX0
01-05 08:50:33.741 E/Google Maps Android API( 8860):    Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): BF:45:E2:59:BF:E1:B0:77:66:E0:DC:13:9A:1F:E3:45:8D:F8:E1:41;com.companyname.PruebaMapas
01-05 08:50:33.756 D/        ( 8860): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa5508b40, tid 8919
01-05 08:50:33.758 W/        ( 8860): Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 
01-05 08:50:33.758 W/        ( 8860): Process pipe failed
01-05 08:50:33.763 D/EGL_emulation( 8860): eglCreateContext: 0xa5506140: maj 1 min 0 rcv 1
01-05 08:50:33.767 D/        ( 8860): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7ec86800, tid 8860
01-05 08:50:33.767 W/        ( 8860): Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 
01-05 08:50:33.816 D/EGL_emulation( 8860): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa5506140: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0x8acec820)
01-05 08:50:35.243 W/DynamiteModule( 8860): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
01-05 08:50:35.247 I/DynamiteModule( 8860): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0
01-05 08:50:35.247 E/GoogleCertificates( 8860): Failed to load com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates
01-05 08:50:35.247 E/GoogleCertificates( 8860): qq: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
01-05 08:50:35.247 E/GoogleCertificates( 8860):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509470:11)
01-05 08:50:35.247 E/GoogleCertificates( 8860):     at in.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509470:12)
01-05 08:50:35.247 E/GoogleCertificates( 8860):     at in.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509470:31)
01-05 08:50:35.247 E/GoogleCertificates( 8860):     at in.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509470:30)
01-05 08:50:35.247 E/GoogleCertificates( 8860):     at iy.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509470:35)
01-05 08:50:35.247 E/GoogleCertificates( 8860):     at iy.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509470:20)
01-05 08:50:35.247 E/GoogleCertificates( 8860):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.ev.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509470:143)
01-05 08:50:35.247 E/GoogleCertificates( 8860):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fb.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11509470:28)
01-05 08:50:35.247 E/GoogleCertificates( 8860):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
01-05 08:50:35.247 E/GoogleCertificates( 8860):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
01-05 08:50:35.247 E/GoogleCertificates( 8860):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #4
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #8
El subproceso 0x4 terminó con código 0 (0x0).
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #8
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #9
El subproceso 0x8 terminó con código 0 (0x0).
```

I also have problems when I'm trying to see the results on the UWP solution, I have an exception. The code I use is, in MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace PruebaMapas.UWP
{
public sealed partial class MainPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init();
        LoadApplication(new PruebaMapas.App());
    }
}
}
```

And the error I have is here:

```
        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
        }
        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
```

---

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
#endif
```

Why I can't see the google maps information?  Can anyone helps me? Thanks!

Comment: What is the exception? Did you try to debug the exception?

Comment: I don't have an exception on Android app, it loads Google Maps but it shows nothing.

Comment: Quote from above "I have an exception." And now you say, I don't have an exception.... Which one is it?

Comment: When I write "I have an exception", I write before "On the UWP solution", not at Android solution. So, on Android app I don't have an exception. On UWP solution, it breaks at:             if (rootFrame.Content == null)
            {
                // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
                // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
                // parameter
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
            }
            Window.Current.Activate();

Comment: I post the error line on the question, for seeing better

Comment: Android is caching the credentials sometimes. Uninstall the app from the device or emulator, rebuild and try again.

Also, Google Maps will write to the output window if there is something wrong. Have you checked that too?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I see the output window, and I have an exception (I think its an Authorization failure). I put that exception on the question. Can you help me one more time? Thanks!

Comment: @tequilaslammer I just write it after the screenshot

Comment: @tequilaslammer NEWS: I delete the android restriction on the API Credentials and it shows the map correctly. Why? Any idea?

Comment: I collected my comments into an answer so you can mark it as the one that helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see the Google logo but no tiles for the map it is often an indicator that something went wrong with the authorization at the Google Maps API.

Your output also says so too:

01-05 08:50:33.741 E/Google Maps Android API( 8860): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.

A possible cause that I often see during development is that there was a mistake in setting  up the api key in the console or in the manifest. If the app was then deployed to a device/ emulator Android caches the wrong credentials. To over come this delete the app, rebuild with the correct key and re-deploy. It should now work as expected.